# why Array object become empty if input file pass as an array element in ajax request without form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, form-data, asyncfileupload

when I try to upload the file after selecting without assigning it to an array it works fine but when assigning the file object as an element of an array $_FILES become empty

**HTML**

```
<input type='file' name='image' class='image'>
```

**Script**

```
var img = $('.image').prop('files')[0];
var ajax_data=['product','price',img];

var postData = new FormData();
    postData.append('data',ajax_data);


$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     processData: false, 
     contentType: false, 
     url: base_url + "/admin/create_bill",
     data:postData,
     success: function (data) {
                  alert('data has been submitted')
            }
 });
}
});
```

note:
if is use JSON.stringify(ajax_data) all the array element successfully pass to the server only file object becomes empty
while i does not use JSON.stringify() $_FILES become empty

in a simple word I want to pass an array which contains file object and plain string data

Comment: Why are you uploading a JavaScript object (array) instead of `FormData` or `File` object itself?

Comment: No `FormData` is used at the code at the question

Answer (score 1):

You can `POST` `FormData` object to server including the necessary data. If the requirement is the upload an array, you can convert the `File` object to a `data URL` string, convert the array to `JSON` and `POST` the `JSON` string to the server.